# XSD import into another XSD file

Tags: eclipse, xsd

I have a problem with imported xsd's.
i have 3 xsd service.xsd, header.xsd and inputmessage.xsd
inputmessage.xsd contains the root element.

service.xsd imports header.xsd and inputmessage xsd.

while generating sample xml of service.xsd in eclipse i get the following error "No root element exists since the scheme provided has no global elements".

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing is typically due to use of schema documents which do not declare an outer element (a 'root element').  The schemas with which you are working may define only complex types (likely with enclosed elements).  The significance of the element w.r.t. file creation is that an element defines the concrete implementation of a type in an xml file (i.e. the name of the element from the schema becomes the tag name in the xml file).  The complex type defines the structure that would apply to an element which is of that type.

In your service.xsd file, try inserting the following (you may need to work with the prefix binding to be consistent with your schema file):

```
<element name="rootElement" type="tns:LocallyDefinedType" />
```

where 'tns' is bound to the schema target namespace and 'LocallyDefinedType' is the name of a complex type defined in the schema document (the type you are hoping to see in the generated xml document).

If this does not help, post your schema documents (or some appropriate dummied-up examples) and a more targeted element declaration can be provided.